# Object-oriented semaphore usage in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, semaphore

I know how to use Unix semaphores in C. Before using them I must call a constructor-ish function named `sem_init` and after using them I have to call a destructor-like function named `sem_destroy`.

I know I can keep doing this in C++ because of its backwards compatibility with C, but does C++ have a real object-oriented way to use semaphores?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928853/how-can-i-achieve-something-similar-to-a-semaphore-using-boost-in-c

Comment: I've heard of Boost before, but haven't used it. Are you saying that I need to download additional libraries if I want to use semaphores in an OO way? Then I'll just stick with the already included `semaphore.h` library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really insist on using POSIX semaphores and not Boost, you can of course wrap `sem_t` in a class:

```
class Semaphore {
    sem_t sem;

  public:
    Semaphore(int shared, unsigned value)
    { sem_init(&sem, shared, value); }

    ~Semaphore() { sem_destroy(&sem); }

    int wait() { return sem_wait(&sem); }
    int try_wait() { return sem_trywait(&sem); }
    int unlock() { return sem_post(&sem); }
};
```

Exercise for the reader: You may want to add exceptions instead of C-style error codes and perhaps other features. Also, this class should be noncopyable. The easiest way to achieve that is inheriting from `boost::noncopyable` ;)

**Edit**: as @Ringding remarks, looping on `EINTR` would be a very wise thing to do.

```
int Semaphore::wait()
{
    int r;
    do {
        r = sem_wait(&sem);
    } while (r == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You should check for EINTR when calling sem_wait and loop accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org) (if you don't know them, they are for C++ what the JDK is for Java).

[Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html) is the library you need for your question. It provides an abstraction over the inter-process communnication mechanisms.

[This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.semaphores.semaphores_anonymous_example) is an example of how to use semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

[C++0x has no semaphores? How to synchronize threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792449/c0x-has-no-semaphores-how-to-synchronize-threads/4793662#4793662)