# Obtain POSIX semaphore's name

Tags: c++, linux, unix, posix, semaphore

is there any way to obtain a POSIX named semaphore's name given its ID (sem_t) within C++?

Thanks to all and best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is no `sem_name` (or whatever you'd call it) function in the [POSIX semaphore spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/semaphore.h.html). There is also no Linux-specific workaround, since it provides no `sem_name` either and it does not store the name in the `sem_t`, which is defined in `<bits/semaphore.h>` as

```
typedef union
{
  char __size[__SIZEOF_SEM_T];
  long int __align;
} sem_t;
```

The files `/proc/sys/kernel/sem` and `/proc/sysvipc/sem` don't seem to contain this information either.

So, your best option is to store the name yourself when doing `sem_open`, preferably in a wrapper class. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803900/object-oriented-semaphore-usage-in-c/4804234#4804234) for an example wrapper class.